# Multiply Hex > uint32> back to Hex

Tags: c, python-3.x, hex, unsigned-integer

I am attempting to find the product (multiply) two hexadecimal numbers (57c9f63e & 16f77ed6) and print them as an unsigned 32 bit int, and finally convert that unsigned int back to hex.

I have a short python program to convert hex to decimal which I think I would need to convert the hex to decimal, then multiply and find the previous items. However, I have no idea where to start and if structs are needed to complete this.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: You have tagged it `C`, you want a `C` solution or python one?

Comment: I truthfully am just trying to learn how it would be done in either language. I am currently using python for a course, so python would be great. Thanks for the quick replies everyone

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you can use hexadecimal number in multiplication. The hex representation doesn't cause any problem. (`0x` is basically making it a hex representation).

The code will be something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main(){
    uint32_t a = 0x57c9f63e ;
    uint32_t b = 0x16f77ed6 ;
    uint32_t res = a*b;
    if( b && res/b != a){
        printf("%s\n","overflow!!!" );
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("0x%" PRIu32 "\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Yes there is overflow when we use `uint32_t`. But `uint64_t` can hold the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main(){
    uint64_t a = 0x57c9f63e ;
    uint64_t b = 0x16f77ed6 ;
    uint64_t res = a*b;
    if( b && res/b != a){
        printf("%s\n","overflow!!!" );
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("0x%" PRIu64 "\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the result, `0x567517894676077524`.

Answer (score 0):

No conversion is necessary - you can read integers in either hex or decimal format, do the multiplication, then write the output in either hex or decimal format:

```
>>> x = input("Gimme a number in hex format: ")
Gimme a number in hex format: 0x57c9f63e
>>> y = input("Gimme a number in hex format: ")
Gimme a number in hex format: 0x16f77ed6
>>> z = y * x
>>> '%d %x' % (z, z)
'567517894676077524 7e03a84b3d85bd4'
>>> type(z)
<type 'int'>
```

Granted this is Python 2.4.2, not 3.x, so things may be different with input, although I'm pretty sure 3.x does something similar.  The leading `0x` is necessary to tell Python the input is in hex format.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the above code, after multiplying both numbers, do I just need to convert to unsigned 32 then back to hex?

Comment: @Mike - hex is just a display format; nothing's *stored* in hex or decimal.